# Tar input/output error

Tags: files, tar

I used tar to archive some important files. After converting all my files to `.tar` I tested it and there was no problem so I deleted all my files. Next day I tried it again and I got this error:

```
tar -xvf my_file.tar
/*
 * tar lists all my files here but extract just some of them
 */
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: my_file.tar: Cannot read: Input/output error
tar: Too many errors, quitting
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Even when I try to copy my tar file to another directory I get this error:

```
Error splicing file: Input/output error
```

My files were stored on an `NTFS` partition and on an external hard drive. Ubuntu `Disks` program says `SELF-TEST FAILED` when I press `Start Self-test`. What can I do now to recover my files? They are important stuff of my university.

Comment: Please describe which command line you used to create the tarfile, and which command line you are using to extract from the tarfile.

Comment: I used Archive Manager.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of the following command line, `tar -tvf file.tar` if the tarfile is not compressed. (If compressed, please tell us what kind of compression.)

Comment: Please write the exact name of the file so we can see the file `extension`

Comment: @sudodus no problem with `tar -tvf my_file.tar`. Tar lists all my files without any error.

Comment: I seems that the tarfile is damaged or maybe the file system is damaged. Since there are important data I suggest that you clone the drive and do repair/recovery work on the cloned copy. See this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986 - scroll down to  'Advanced repair ...', Maybe it helps to repair the file system, maybe you can recover the tarfile with some tool for example PhotoRec.

Comment: Sounds to me like a disk problem. If the disk is a external one, try using a shorter and better USB cable. The disk might be damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank heavens I could recover all my files except two of them using a Windows system and Winrar. The problem was bad sectors. I could extract my files individually. I found that both Winrar and Tar don't extract the rest of an archive when they face a bad sector. I couldn't extract my files one by one by Tar but Winrar could do the job.